# Sqlite database update error

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to run an update statement.  The method located in database class is below.

I'm passing the variables to the method correctly and the code that runs without exception.  However when I LogCat, the column value does not change. I don't know what or where the problem is...can someone please help me?

```
public Cursor updateStatus(int ID,String status) {
    return database.rawQuery("Update events set status= '"+status+"' where _id=" + ID, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `execSQL()` instead of `rawQuery()` to execute SQL like this.

`rawQuery()` alone just compiles the SQL but does not run it.